# In React, trying to refresh and stay on same page but state will not update as expected

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, google-authentication, stitch

My app uses react, react-router-dom and stitch which is accessing mongodb and handling the auth through google. I am able to authenticate and and access the ProtectedPage component but when I refresh, isAuthed will not have a value and I will redirect to /login. Why is state not being update so that isAuthed = true and how would I ensure that I am taken to /protected when i refresh?

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {
  Switch,
  Route,
  Link,
  Redirect,
  withRouter,
} from "react-router-dom";
import {Stitch, GoogleRedirectCredential} from 'mongodb-stitch-browser-sdk'

import './App.css';

class App extends Component{

  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = {
      isAuthed: ''
    }
  }

  componentDidMount(){
    
    this.client = new Stitch.initializeDefaultAppClient("myAppId");

    if(this.client.auth.hasRedirectResult()){
      this.client.auth.handleRedirectResult();
    }
    
    this.setState({isAuthed: this.client.auth.isLoggedIn});
  }


  login = () => {
    const credential = new GoogleRedirectCredential() 
    this.user = this.client.auth.loginWithRedirect(credential);
  }

  logout = () => {
    this.client.auth.logout();
    this.setState({isAuthed: false});
  }

  showUser = () => {
    console.log(this.client.auth.isLoggedIn);
    console.log(this.client);
  }


  render() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
    <ul>
      <li>
        <Link to="/">Public Page</Link>
      </li>
      <li>
        <Link to="/login">Login</Link>
      </li>
      <li>
      <Link to="/protected">Protected Page</Link>
    </li>
    </ul>

    <Switch>
      <Route exact path="/">
        <PublicPage isAuthed={this.state.isAuthed}/>
      </Route>
      <Route path="/login" >
        <LoginPage login={this.login} isAuthed={this.state.isAuthed}/>
      </Route>
      <PrivateRoute path="/protected" isAuthed={this.state.isAuthed} >
        <ProtectedPage logout={this.logout} />
      </PrivateRoute>
    </Switch>

    </div>
  );
  }
}

export default withRouter(App);

function PublicPage() {
 
  return (
    <div><h3>Public</h3>
    </div>
    
  );

}

function ProtectedPage({logout}) {
 
  return (
      <div>
      <h3>You Are Logged In</h3>
        <button onClick={logout}>Logout</button>
      </div>
    );
}

function LoginPage({login}) {

  return (


    <div>
      <p>You must log in to view the page</p>
      <button onClick={login}>Log in</button>
    </div>
    
  );
}

function PrivateRoute({ children, isAuthed, client, ...rest}) {
  console.log(isAuthed);

  return (
    <Route
      {...rest}
      render={({ location }) =>
      isAuthed ? (
          children
        ) : (
          <Redirect
            to={{
              pathname: "/login",
              state: { from: location }
            }}
          />
        )
      }
    />
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

ComponentDidMount get called only after the render method called for the first time. Try putting the code in componentWillMount instead of componentDidMount.

I would suggest to store the user information in browser localstorage instead of storing isAuthed in state.

Comment: I don't know why I never thought of componentWillMount... Spent almost 3 hours on a similar issue this answer helped a lot thank you!

Answer (score 0):

State is ephemeral in React. Whenever you do a reload of a page or do a redirect that causes a GET request for a new page the state resets to whatever you set as the default, which in the case of `this.state.isAuthed` is `""`.

To resolve the issue, you can save the `isAuthed` state in `localStorage` or as a cookie whenever a user logs in. You can then pull in that value and set your state when the page first loads by either using `componentDidMount` or `useEffect`.

Just make sure to clear your `localStorage` or cookie values for `isAuthed` when a user logs out.